# Compare string values inside a hash in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to sort this hash in alphabetical order .This is my hash structure

```
my $hash = {
          'names' => [
            {
              'state' => 'I',
              'names' => 'INTTEST',
            },
            {
              'state' => 'I',
              'names' => 'TEST',
            },
            {
              'state' => 'D',
              'names' => 'GREATTEST',
            },
            {
              'state' => 'I',
              'names' => 'Stest',
            },
            {
              'state' => 'I',
              'names' => 'Atest',
            },
            {
              'state' => 'D',
              'names' => 'SPtest',
            },
            ]
        };
```

What i have tried is

```
my @sorted_data = (sort { lc($b->{names}) cmp lc($a->{names});} $hash->{names});
```

I want to return the same structure to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dereference `$hash->{names}` array,

```
use feature 'fc';
my @sorted_data = sort{ fc($b->{names}) cmp fc($a->{names}) } @{$hash->{names}};
```

[`fc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) checks if two strings are equal regardless of case

If you want to sort in place, just assign result back to originating array,

```
@{$hash->{names}} = sort{ fc($b->{names}) cmp fc($a->{names}) } @{$hash->{names}};
```

Comment: i want to return the data in same structure as i have posted in the question

Comment: Undefined subroutine &TOOL::Function::fc called at

Comment: it's not sorting my data

Comment: @PerlDeveloper use `lc` if your perl older than v5.16